# Axios instance not getting the token from local storage on first call - React js + django

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I created an Axios instance to set up the baseURL and the headers. The header also needs to contain the token for authorization. So when a user logs in I call an API to fetch some data related to the user using useEffect. So the API gets called immediately after the login is completed. This API needs permissions and hence requires the token. On login, I store the token in local storage but for some reason, the token is not loaded on the first call of the instance and I get an **Unauthorised** error from the backend. But then if I manually reload the page, the API gets called again but this time the token is received by the instance and the data is fetched. Below is my code.

**axios instance**

```
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

// getting the token from the localstorage
let authTokens = localStorage.getItem("token")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
  : null;

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${authTokens?.access}` },
});
```

**api call**

```
export const fetchTeacherDetail = async () => {
 
  try {
    let response = await axiosInstance.get(`/teacher/get-detail/`);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    ToastNotification(
      "We are facing some errors. Please trying again later.",
      "error"
    );
  }
};
```

I followed a youtube video to learn this, he is not getting this error but for some reason I am getting this error. Please suggest to me what should I do.

**Update**

code to show where I store the token in the local storage

**action that stores the token and user details in redux**

```
export const loginUser = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    // before calling the api
    dispatch(loginPending());

    //calling the api
    const response = await userLogin(email, password);
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      return dispatch(loginFail(response.status));
    } else {
      dispatch(loginSuccess(response.data));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(loginFail(error.message));
  }
};
```

**userLogin() API code**

```
export const userLogin = async (email, password) => {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`${url}/token/`, body, config);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response.data));
      return response;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    ToastNotification("Credentials provided are not valid", "error");
  }
};
```

**mocking value of the response.data received int the above function**

```
 refresh: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTY1ODU4NTUxMSwiaWF0IjoxNjUwODA5NTExLCJqdGkiOiI4NDRjZWFjNTFkOWI0OGNkOWE0MTFlYzU4ZWY4ZDMxYiIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiI0YjdhODEzYmFkYi05VzZXIiOmZhbHNlLCJpc19zdGFmZiI6ZmFsc2V9.zlGb4tPtJ9HlUvSUZW6QrHHfDsUU8hZ6rliYc3RbJXQ',
access: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjU4NTg1NTExLCJpYXQiOjEk1MTEsImp0aSI6ImEyYzg1NzAyZmY0ZjQ4YmRiZjEwZjEzNTUwYjk0MzE2IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6lciI6dHJ1Zsc2UsImlzX3N1cGVydXNlciI6ZmFsc2UsImlzX3N0YWZmIjpmYWxzZX0.qrictVbES22dGpA0dpVA5KLTZkrMsCM0hDHq2Yrs
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you save the token to the localStorage?

Comment: @GMaiolo Yes, I have updated the question. Please have a look

Comment: What is `response.data` exactly when you POST to `/token`?

Comment: @GMaiolo response.data is the refresh and the access token provided by django on login

Comment: Can you provide the exact content of it (mocking values, of course), we need to see the structure to see if it matches what you expect

Comment: @GMaiolo I have updated the question. Please have a look

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue probably happens because you set the axios instance token on the application startup, but never update it upon login.

You would need to "refresh" the value when a login happens by checking again for the localStorage data.

A quick solution would be to calculate the headers every time you call the API

```
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

export const getToken = () => localStorage.getItem("token")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
  : null;

export const getAuthorizationHeader = () => `Bearer ${getToken()}`;

export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: { Authorization: getAuthorizationHeader() },
});
```

And then in the API call

```
export const fetchSomething = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get("/foo", { 
      headers: { Authorization: getAuthorizationHeader() }
    });

    return response;

  } catch (error) {
    // error handling
  }
};
```

---

Another solution would be mutating the axios instance when a login happens by doing something like this

```
axiosInstance.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${result.access}`
```

Comment: Okay I understand, but since I am using useEffect, this means the API is called after the page has loaded. So by that time the token is available in the storage right? So why is it not getting the value on first call?

Comment: If the API call is called after the page has loaded but the user hasn't logged in yet then it won't work. If the user has already logged in I assume the token should be present, which you can check by console logging it.

Comment: Yes, the user logs in and is redirected to that page. So basically the user on login gets the token before the redirection.  And also the token is immediately available in the storage I have checked. So why I need to recheck the token?

Comment: @RitankarBhattacharjee you mentioned getting an `Unauthorized` error because the token wasn't picking up. If you see that the token is correct and you get a bad response from the server then the error could be in the backend instead.

Comment: No the backend is working fine. I just checked the calling without using the Instance and the token is being received correctly from the storage. Did I do any mistake in getting the token in the Instance?

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code that sets up the instance, my best guess is what I mentioned in the answer, that you're picking the data from `localStorage` before it's actually there. If you don't use the instance you will manually set the headers as I did in the API call example (and it does work, like you mentioned)

Comment: The mutating method that you suggested is working for the time being

Answer (score 9):

You should use AXIOS interceptors, as @GMaiolo said you are not getting your token for the first time when you login in. Or when you cleared your whole cookie session. So when you try to send request to backend for the first time, Your authorization header got the null value. So you can easily solved it with
AXIOS interceptors. By doing this you don't have to use config param for each CRUD operations from Front-end.

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    if (user) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${user.token}`;
    }
    console.log("request config", config);
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    // console.log("request error", error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

Comment: Hello. I have a problem. When I try to use the `axiosInstance` inside next.js `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` I face `localStorage is not defined` and I can not send an `authorized request` to my backend and face `401`. Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Sorry for late response, localStorage is a browser API and is not available on the server-side. getStaticProps and getServerSideProps are executed on the server-side, so you can't access the localStorage from there.

Comment: When the user logs in, you can store the token as a cookie or in the browser's localStorage. Then, when you make a request to your backend, you can include the token as a cookie or a header.

Answer (score 1):

i do believe the problem not in the backend since you need to refresh manually to make authorization fine so no need to worry about the backend what is your problem is your are storing the value of the token in a `const getToken`
it will be stored there forever, what i mean if it gets it in the beginning as bad token or null it will be always the same initial value so what you have to do is:

```
const baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${
      localStorage.getItem("token")
        ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token")).access
        : null
    }`,
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you I just edited your code a bit and now it is working fine. Thank you so much

Comment: I just worked for one moment and it not working again

Comment: So weird make you sure you didn't trigger logout or the token may has been expired and yes don't forget to add JSON.parse around the localstorage.getItem

Comment: No logout has not been triggred, and I used parsed to get the access one but still the same problem persists

Comment: So the problem is the same need to refresh the page to work right? not something new

Comment: Yes yes this is the problem

Comment: My solution was a simple solution just to make things clear for you, but what the first answer aims exactly at the problem that i pointed and gives a clean solution for you but if you sure it didn't work! and with all the actions happened that my solution worked for a moment and  then didn't , it may be the back end that when the access token is expired it returns 401 instead of generating another one and send or you didn't handle the case of when new token generated and got from server should be set in the localstorage